# umbraco event generation

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, umbraco

How can we add events to a button using umbraco? My requirement is I have a button "button1" which is in a usercontrol page "login.ascx".whenever I click the button I need to go to home.ascx

```
<div style="border: 1px red;margin:30px 0px 0px 0px;width:auto; height: auto;text-align:center;" 
id="login" runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtpass" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="login" />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Register" onclick="Button2_Click" 
    style="height: 26px" />
 <br />
<asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can't redirect to a usercontrol ie can't go from login.ascx to home.ascx.

You can do one thing add the login usercontrol as macro in one content page in umbraco and add home.ascx as other macro in other content page.

Then you can redirect from one content page to other using Response.Redirect.

Comment: @mahesh how to set the link to document of a page

Comment: link to document? can't understand

Comment: i have two pages.when i create the page it has a defauilt url.now i want to change it.how can i done it?

Comment: i think you created page via umbraco cms

Comment: yeah...any other way?i created page using umbraco and add my usercontrols in it

Comment: you can edit the name by going into the properties tab and change the name

Comment: there is no option in the proeprty tab to edit the url.check this link (http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbraco-best-practices/umbracourlname).i think this is the only way.but i dnt understand wht it exactly means?

Comment: the given url is not working. you can add another url by going to manage hostname section for a content. This can be obtained by right clicking the content section

Comment: that i tried.but manage hostname is not replace the default hostname.it only add a new link to that page:-(

Comment: it means you can access it in both urls ie in default and in the newly added link

Comment: i want my login page with default url and after login home page with default\home.aspx...but nw its login with default\home.aspx and homepage with default url....

Answer (score 0):

With .NET usercontrols in Umbraco, you write them in exactly the same way you would for any other ASP.NET webforms application/website.
Your code-behind should look like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Response.Redirect("~/home.aspx");
}
```

If you want to specify a particular content node to redirect to, then you can specify a property on your usercontrol, and then when you create your Umbraco macro in the Developer section, you will be able to include the usercontrol property as a macro property, and add a Content Picker type to it to make it user-friendly for an admin to specify which page to redirect to. Example:

```
partial class MyUserControl : UserControl {
    public int NodeToRedirectTo { get; set; }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Response.Redirect(umbraco.library.NiceUrl(NodeToRedirectTo));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Benjamin